# python how to use string value for custom sort?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I have an datafremae like this

```
   time_posted
0   5 days ago
1  an hour ago
2    a day ago
3  6 hours ago
4  4 hours ago
```

I tried this `df.sort_values(by='time_posted',ascending=True)` and getting this result:

```
   time_posted
4  4 hours ago
0   5 days ago
3  6 hours ago
2    a day ago
1  an hour ago
```

But I want to short value by `hours ago` so my datframe will be look like this

```
   time_posted
1  an hour ago
4  4 hours ago
3  6 hours ago
2    a day ago
0   5 days ago
```

Comment: hi, can you detail what is the unit (dtype) of your column ? btw you must convert all into hours, then sort

Comment: David Leon all are string data. I don't want to convert theme hours or date time. I want to keep theme as string

Comment: in my opinion it would be better to store time_posted in numeric type then to convert to string when needed. But as an answer to your specification you should create a temporary column with string converted to hours, filter your df according to this new col and then drop this column

Comment: David Leon can you show me how can I can filter all hours data and move theme to new rows then use sort.

Comment: Looks like you're going to need to write a custom parser for those strings in order to normalise them to (numerical) hours

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you remove the "ago" and replace "a/an" by 1, you can feed the values to [`pandas.to_timedelta`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_timedelta.html):

```
(pd.to_timedelta(df['time_posted']
.str.replace(r'\ban?\b', '1', regex=True)
.str.replace(' ago', '', regex=False))
)
```

output:

```
0   5 days 00:00:00
1   0 days 01:00:00
2   1 days 00:00:00
3   0 days 06:00:00
4   0 days 04:00:00
Name: time_posted, dtype: timedelta64[ns]
```

This enables you to get a sorted order:

```
idx = (pd.to_timedelta(df['time_posted']
 .str.replace(r'\ban?\b', '1', regex=True)
 .str.replace(' ago', '', regex=False))
 .sort_values()
 .index
)

df.loc[idx]
```

output:

```
   time_posted
1  an hour ago
4  4 hours ago
3  6 hours ago
2    a day ago
0   5 days ago
```

Comment: mozway I might be an day ago. I have an idea how to use .str.contains for select all hous ago data then create another  new column for those selected data

Comment: I used this `[df_a['time_posted'].str.contains('hours')]` which selecting all hours data but can't create another new column.

Comment: @ByHala I don't understand your comment, is my approach working for you? If not can you provide a counter-example?

Comment: getting `ValueError: invalid unit abbreviation: month`

Comment: @ByHala Indeed, values such as "month" or "year" are invalid as they are ambiguous. To give you an example, you can't tell which is greater between "30 days" and "1 month", the month could be less (February), equal (April), or more (January) than 30 days. While units such as "week", "day", or "hours" can be converted unambiguously between each other. To handle ambiguous units you could choose to accept an approximation by replacing "x month(s)" by "30*x days".

Answer (score 1):

One answer could be the following

**set example data**

```
import pandas as pd

#your dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(time_posted=['5 days ago', 'an hour ago', 'a day ago', '6 hours ago', '4 hours ago']))
```

**Conversion func**

You have to split the string and take a decision on the different values (here `x[0]` a value and `x[1]` a unit)

```
def to_hours(s):
    x = s.split(' ')

    if x[0].lower() in ['a','an']:
        a = 1
    else:
        a = float(x[0])

    x1 = x[1].lower()
    b = 1 # 1 hour
    if x[1].startswith('day'):
        b = b*24 # 1 day = 24 hours
    
    return a*b
```

**Application**

```
df['hours'] = df.time_posted.apply(to_hours) # apply hours conversion
df = df.sort_values('hours',ascending=True)[['time_posted']]# Sort and skip non-necessary col

print(df)
```

output:

```
time_posted
1  an hour ago
4  4 hours ago
3  6 hours ago
2    a day ago
0   5 days ago
```

Comment: I also have `a month ago` so I am getting `a month ago` very first of my index